# How to display one div at random, with defined durations for the length of display for each?

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently utilizing the below jquery written by another user to randomly display one div at a time. Each div is shown for the same amount of time.

```
var divs = $('.parent').children('.child'), //fetch all the divs
    len = divs.length, //number of divs on page
    randomDiv, //random number that will be generated
    speed = 10000; //interval in miliseconds for the new div to appear
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    randomDiv = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    divs.removeClass('show');
    divs.eq(randomDiv).addClass('show');
}, speed);
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" id="one">One</div>
    <div class="child" id="two">Two</div>
    <div class="child" id="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.child{display:none;}
.child.show{display: block;}
```

I require each of the divs, uniquely identified by id (or additional classname if required), to be displayed for a defined period of time. For example div id 'one' to be displayed for eight seconds, div id two to be displayed for seven seconds, div id three to be displayed for nineteen seconds, etc.

I suspect the solution resides somewhere within the speed variable, I just can't put it together.

Also is it possible to implement a jquery based fade in/out when each div appears/disappears.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    randomDiv = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    divs.removeClass('show');
    divs.eq(randomDiv).addClass('show');
    setTimeout(function() {
        divs.eq(randomDiv).removeClass('show');
    }, speed);
}, speed);
```

Comment: Thanks Chen. Does this specify a length of time for the display of each div?

Comment: the 'speed' variable will hold that value in ms

Answer (score 0):

***Updated**

Try this:

```
var divs = $('.parent').children('.child'), //fetch all the divs
        len = divs.length, //number of divs on page
        randomDiv, //random number that will be generated
        speed;

function start() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    var id;
    while (rand == randomDiv) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    }
    randomDiv = rand;
    id = divs.eq(randomDiv).attr('id');
    if (id === 'one') {
        speed = 2000;
    } else if (id === 'two') {
        speed = 4000;
    } else if (id === 'three') {
        speed = 8000;
    }
    divs.removeClass('show');
    divs.eq(randomDiv).addClass('show');
    setTimeout(function() {
        start();
    }, speed);
}

start();
```

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/pX9xX/10/)

Comment: Many thanks for your response Manov, but the duration of display for each div appears to change each time the div is displayed. Is it possible that occasionally the display of a div is repeating itself, or does the randomDiv function  avoid that?

Comment: `random` does not avoid duplication and it is possible that you will see same div, to avoid duplication you can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/pX9xX/9/

Comment: Thanks Manov. There is still an inconsistency with the amount of time with which the divs are displaying however. For div id 'two' I have specified to display for 4000 milliseconds, it is displaying anywhere from 2 seconds to ten seconds though. In the above jquery what is the `speed` specification on line 4 doing?

Comment: Answer has been updated to fixed the inconsistency and `speed` specification on line 4 is not in use so removed it's value, demo link http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/pX9xX/10